# subprocess - Игнорируется часть функции

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
def corruptit(filE):
    time.sleep(1)
    subprocess.call(f"echo '' > {filE}", shell=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    os.rename(filE, filE + ".cpt")
    # time.sleep(1)


def corrupter():
    files = input("Write names of files via space or ALL(ALLbyct[gry]):\n")
    loca = input("Type location: ")
    if files == 'gry':
        extension = input("Write extension name: ")
        for item in os.listdir(loca):
            if item.endswith("." + extension):
                corruptit(item)
    elif files == 'ALL' or files == 'all':
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(loca):
            print("root", root)
            # print("subdirs", subdirs)
            print("files", files)
            print("-"*10)
            for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith(".cpv"):
                    pass
                else:
                    corruptit(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Здравствуйте.Имеется папка с несколькими файлами. Моя задача обнулить их размер. При вызове функции corruptit, вместо записи пустой строки в файл - файлы просто переименовываются, игнорируя `subprocess.call(f"echo '' > {filE}", shell=True)`.

C чем это связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во-первых вызов `subprocess.call(f"echo '' > {filE}", shell=True)` не обнуляет файл а просто заменяет содержимое на `b"''\n"`. Т.е. технически этот вызов ошибки не несет. Если и есть проблемы, то они возможно связаны с передаваемыми аргументами.

Во-вторых не очень ясна мотивация использования модуля `subprocess` для работы с фаловыми данными. В Python для этих целей существуют модули [io](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html?highlight=io#module-io), [os](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os), а также встроенная функция [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?#open), позволяющие редактировать как содержимое, так и метаданные файлов. К тому же приведенный код **не является переносимым**.

В-третьих мне кажется, что вызовы `time.sleep(1)` излишни (если только это ни какая-нибудь хитрая задумка). Во всяком случае они не имеют отношения к указанной функциональности.

С учетом всего этого, я бы определил функцию `corruptit` следующим образом:

```
import os

def corruptit(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'bw'): pass
    os.rename(filepath, filepath + ".cpt")
```

или

```
def corruptit(filepath):
    with open(filepath + ".cpt", 'bw'): pass
    os.remove(filepath)
```